# Possible to have one app on Heroku that dynamically uses different databases?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I have an idea for a multi-tenant app, and I'm trying to decide if I should use one large database or use separate databases for each tenant.

I don't even know if the latter is possible in Rails, or with rails on Heroku.

I also don't know if this is a good idea, or cost prohibitive.

But I guess to start I just want to know if it's possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many approaches to multi-tenancy, each with its own pros and cons. Postgres has this nice feature called `schemas`, which means you can have one database but multiple namespaces inside. This can be a convenient solution for Rails, as Rails was designed for connecting with only one database. It is easy to integrate with [apartment gem](https://github.com/influitive/apartment). It takes care of migrations and tenant switching based on specified rules, usually subdomain. But this solution has downsides. While Postgres does not have any limitation on number of schemas, when you have a lot, migrations will take forever. And there are problems with backups. Heroku recommends using less than 50 schemas.

If you want to have multiple physical databases then it is a little bit tricky with Rails. There are some gems that allow connecting to multiple databases. Recently I heard about [octoshark gem](https://github.com/dalibor/octoshark), but I haven't use it.

In summary, Postgres schemas are nice if you want to have good isolation without too much work. It will be also cost efficient on Heroku, as you will use only one database. But it won't scale for a lot of tenants. Multiple databases provide the best isolation, but support for this solution in Rails is not that great I think. And it will be costly as you you will need to provision separate database for each tenant. And the last resort is to just use one database and scope all your tenant data with `tenant_id`. In this solution you need to guarantee isolation which requires additional work and it is easy to miss some parts of the application.

Comment: great answer! Thank you!